# Formula won't update when cell automatically updates based on input from other sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a formula on sheet 5 (Shaker Spares) that I want to automatically update when I input data into sheet 3 (Shaker Data Entry) cell C13.

I've entered the following code in sheet 5 (Shaker Spares):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Call Shkr_Spares(Target)
End Sub
```

.

```
Private Sub Shkr_Spares(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Select Case Target.Value

        Case 0
            Rows("2:210").EntireRow.Hidden = False
                ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
        Case 1
            Rows("2:16").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("17:210").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
        Case 2
            Rows("17:67").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("68:210").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("3:16").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
        Case 3
            Rows("68:116").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("117:210").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("3:67").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
        Case 4
            Rows("117:145").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("146:210").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("3:116").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
        Case 5
            Rows("146:161").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("161:210").EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Rows("3:145").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
        Case 6
            Rows("162:210").EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Rows("3:161").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Select
  End Select

 End Sub
```

But the code wont work when input is changed in sheet 3 (Shaker Data Entry).

I have no idea how to make sheet 5 work with data input into C13 of sheet 3.

Comment: Put another `Worksheet_Change` in sheet 5 to call the function `call Worksheet("sheet 5").Shkr_Spares(Worksheet("sheet 5").Range ("C1"))`

Comment: Looking at your code, you may need to activate sheet 5 before calling the sub... and you need to put it in sheet 3... not sheet 5... sorry